# Is it possible to reduce Router Solicitation packets and can I altogther remove them

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberrypi-cm3 module that is connected to the internet via a GSM module. In my quest to reduce the data usage. I downloaded `tcpdump` and generated a pcap file to understand what is happening.
When I looked at that pcap file. I found that 21 router solicitation packets were sent. Can I reduce the number of router solicitation packets sent.

Edit 1: So I am trying to answer all the comments here.

1. My biggest payload on an idle system are a. NTP b. DHCP request-response c. Router solicitation. I was thinking I can reduce the NTP by changing the max poll and min poll in NTP.conf file. But I don't know If I can change a configuration file to do the same for Router solicitation
2. I am not using VPN tunneling at this moment. But I would like to implement it. For better debugging, In fact, I am actually working towards it
3. At this moment, No I do not think that I require that. So I will try disabling that as well.
4. Finally I will be attaching my tcpdump file shortly. My system is currently under 24hour test

Comment: No. They are required so that routers can find neighbouring routers.

Comment: Are they the biggest payload?

Comment: Probably, especially if you are not using dynamic routing for another r-pi on the other side. I.e you don't need routing protocols unless you are sending traffic between multiple lans. You should add more info to the question, are you tunneling to this r-pi via VPN?

Comment: Does your GSM network require IPv6? (for example, T-Mobile's cellular data networks in the US require IPv6 now). If not, you might consider disabling IPv6 on that interface.